# Trying to apply a relative transform matrix to a fabricjs PathGroup

Tags: html, svg, fabricjs

Using FabricJS, I have a vector that like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/sb63df47/

As you can see, the `viewBox` is set `0 0 100 100`, even though if the vector were trimmed of whitespace, the `viewBox` would be set to `0 0 30 30`. So to make the bounding box appear closer to the icon, I set the width / height to `30` and `30`. However when I do that, the sub-paths in the PathGroup object are off (by `35` on the top and `35` on the left).

To deal with this, I applied a transformation matrix to "move" the paths back up to where they need to be. But doing this introduces a whole bunch of other problems. Specifically, when I rotate the vector, the transformation is off (see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKU5R.png)

Is there a more elegant way of narrowing the viewBox of a PathGroup if I know the exact width / height that I want it to be set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every SVG is a particular situation,
In any case if you want to modify the objects you have to pay attention to transform Attribute.

Here there is a translate transform that is moving the object of 35x and 35y.
Remove the transform attribute from the group containing paths and the cross will be positioned in the top left corner of the bounding box.

Then if you want to make the bounding box shrink, change the viewbox to `0 0 30 30`

An equivalent transformation is to set up the viewbox to `35 35 30 30` that will apply both a movement in the corner and a shrink.

There are so many ways to obtain the same effect.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns" viewBox="0 0 30 30" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px"><title>add</title><desc>Created with Sketch.</desc><g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage"><g sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" fill="#000000"><g sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" ><path d="M0,14 L30,14 L30,16 L0,16 L0,14 Z" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path><path d="M14,0 L16,0 L16,29.94 L14,29.94 L14,0 Z" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path></g></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks @AndreaBogazzi I will try that. I managed to get the same effect by applying a `transformMatrix`, but this way may be simpler :)